# How to have multilingual custom 404?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual Drupal 7 site for which I have set up a translated 404-page accessed at `mydomain.com/404` and `mydomain.com/en/404`. In the Drupal settings for 404-page I enter just the path `404`.

However, when visiting a non existant URL on the English version, the default language is still being used.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With i18n module pack, there is a module for translating settings, like front page and 404 pages. This means you can setup your 404 page per language, fx `node/1` for `en` and `node/2` for `fr` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve this is with a single page with different text sections per language using [Language Sections](http://drupal.org/project/language_sections).